# Url dinamica com php

Tags: htaccess

Tenho esse url em meu site

```
categorias.php?id_categoria=1
```

Quero fazer uma regra para ficar

```
produtos/nome-categoria
```

Sendo que o nome da categoria já estou puxando do banco com o php

meu .htacsess está assim com uma regra ja feita para a página inicial

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
    #aqui criamos uma condição para que os arquivos sejam ignorados nas regras abaixo
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  #aqui criamos uma condição para que diretórios sejam ignorados nas regras abaixo
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #aqui definimos onde começa a base das regras

    #fix rules 
    RewriteRule ^pagina-inicial/?$ index.php [NC,L]

    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adicione esta regra:

```
RewriteRule ^produtos/(.*)$ /categorias.php?id_categoria=$1 [NC,L]
```

E para fazer a chamada, a url seria:

```
produtos/categoria
```

**Editada:**

No seu caso seria:

```
RewriteRule ^produtos/(.*)$ categorias.php?id_categoria=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Conforme seu código, deu para entender que ele vai buscar pelo **ID** da categoria, que deve ser um número inteiro. Você deve adaptar o código caso deseje buscar pelo nome da categoria.

Comment: retornou Erro 404.

Mudei o php para buscar pele Nome. produtos/nome-categoria

Comment: Erro 404 significa que a url não foi encontrada. Tente verificar se o caminho está correto.

Comment: Talvez tenha que reiniciar o serviço do Apache

Comment: eu acesso o endereço assim categorias.php?id_categoria=1

Comment: Então ficaria assim: `produtos/1`

Comment: quando coloco

RewriteRule ^produtos/(.*)$ /categorias.php?id_categoria=$1 [NC,L]

retorna o ero 404

Comment: produtos/1 tbm retornou o 404

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61297/discussion-between-carlos-andrade-and-wagner-martins-bodyboard).

Comment: cara soh mais uma coisa
se eu tenho
categorias.php?id_categoria=1&nome_categoria=nome-categoria
e querer acessar assim
categorias/nome-categoria
tem como?

Comment: Wagner, eu acho que você deve criar um outro tópico, porque já foge da pergunta original e você pode ter pontos negativos por isso.

Answer (score -1):

Estou fazendo assim, com a categoria funciona mais como eu coloco a subcategoria também?

```
produtos/nome-categoria/nome-subcategoria


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
    #aqui criamos uma condição para que os arquivos sejam ignorados nas regras abaixo
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  #aqui criamos uma condição para que diretórios sejam ignorados nas regras abaixo
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #aqui definimos onde começa a base das regras

    #fix rules
    RewriteRule ^pagina-inicial/?$ index.php [NC,L]
        #RewriteRule ^produtos/(.*)$ categorias.php?id_categoria=$1 [NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^produtos/(.*)$ categorias.php?id_categoria=$1&nome_categoria=$2 [NC,L]
 RewriteRule ^produtos/(.*)$ subcategorias.php?id_subcategoria=$1&nome_categoria=$2 [NC,L]
        </IfModule>
```